# Error Pushing To Heroku with 2captcha library - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Tags: python, heroku, pip, python-requests, 2captcha

I'm getting this error - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' when I run git push heroku master. It's saying I don't have the requests in my requirements.txt but it's clearly in there. I believe something weird is happening because of 2captcha-python. Any ideas on how I can resolve this error? Included my requirements.txt file and error log below.

Requirements.txt file:

```
requests==2.25.1
2captcha-python==1.1.0
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
bs4==0.0.1
cachetools==4.2.2
certifi==2021.5.30
chardet==4.0.0
df2gspread==1.0.4
google-api-python-client==1.6.7
google-auth==1.31.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.4
gspread==3.7.0
httplib2==0.19.1
idna==2.10
lxml==4.6.3
numpy==1.20.3
oauth2client==4.1.3
oauthlib==3.1.1
pandas==1.2.4
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2021.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rsa==4.7.2
selenium==3.141.0
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.2.1
uritemplate==3.0.1
urllib3==1.26.5
```

Error log:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpacks:
remote:        1. heroku/python
remote:        2. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome
remote:        3. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> No Python version was specified. Using the buildpack default: python-3.9.5
remote:        To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing python-3.9.5
remote: -----> Installing pip 20.2.4, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.36.2
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting requests==2.25.1
remote:          Downloading requests-2.25.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
remote:        Collecting 2captcha-python==1.1.0
remote:          Downloading 2captcha-python-1.1.0.tar.gz (8.8 kB)
remote:            ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
remote:             command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qcbdr2fk/2captcha-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qcbdr2fk/2captcha-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-y8s7an11
remote:                 cwd: /tmp/pip-install-qcbdr2fk/2captcha-python/
remote:            Complete output (9 lines):
remote:            Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:              File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-qcbdr2fk/2captcha-python/setup.py", line 4, in <module>
remote:                from twocaptcha import __version__
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-qcbdr2fk/2captcha-python/twocaptcha/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
remote:                from .api import ApiClient
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-qcbdr2fk/2captcha-python/twocaptcha/api.py", line 3, in <module>
remote:                import requests
remote:            ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to python-selenium-southcarolina.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/python-selenium-southcarolina.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/python-selenium-southcarolina.git'
```

Comment: `2captcha` uses `requests` to download extra data so you have to install it before `2captcha`. But if you run all in one `Requirements` then it first download all modules and later install them - so it install `requests` after it tries do use `requests` to download `2captcha`. So first install all modules except `2captcha` and later install only `2captcha`

Answer (score 0):

`pip` first downloads all modules and later install them. So when `pip` downloads `2captcha` then `requests` is already downloaded but not installed. And this makes problem.

You have to first install all modules except `2captcha` and later install only `2captcha`. OR first install only `requests` and later other modules.

---

**EDIT:**

I can't test it but in documentation you can see that it can use also `setup.py` to install modules. But I don't know if it will run both `setup.py` and `requirements` or only one of them.

On local computer in `venv` I installed both using `setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    install_requires=['requests', 'wheel'],
)

import subprocess

subprocess.run('python -m pip install 2captcha-python', shell=True)
```

and running `python setup.py install` (but `Heroku` should run it automatically)

---

Later I will test it on `Heroku` when I refresh my account.

Comment: This makes sense. How would I first install all the modules except 2captcha and later install only 2captcha? I removed 2captcha-python==1.1.0 from the requirements.txt and was then able to use the below commands to push to heroku. I then added 2captcha-python==1.1.0 back to the requirements.txt but ran into the same error message. What's the correct way to first install all the modules except 2captcha and later install only 2captcha? Commands: $ git add . $ git commit -am "make it better" $ git push heroku master

Comment: I don't heroku to test it but in documentation you can see that it can use also `setup.py` to install elements - but I don't know if it will run both `setup.py` and `requirements`. On local computer in venv I installed both using `setup.py` with `install_requires=['requests']` and `subprocess.run('python -m pip install 2captcha-python', shell=True)`